# Is it possible to print only searched multiple strings by sed?

Tags: linux, osx

I'm trying to extract multiple lines of log by regex.

but log file is large so I getting hard. (about 10GB)..

I tried several ways but can't get wanted result.

1st trying)

1) use regex in 'sublime app'.
=> problem : shows out of memory.

2) use regex in 'ultra edit app'.
=> problem : shows out of memory.

2nd trying)
use 'sed' program in terminal on osx.

used operation)

```
$sed -E -n '/.*output:[\S\s]*?AAA[\S\s]*?END.*/p' ./AppLog.txt
```

AAA is searching key. (USER_ID)

it says 'RE error: repetition-operator operand invalid'.

Here is content of AppLog.txt.

```
:
:
DEBUG|2018-03-27,14:41:43.089|print log
DEBUG|2018-03-27,14:41:43.089|print log
DEBUG|2018-03-27,14:41:43.089|output:
=============================================
[START]
00 USER_ID                   = {"AAA"}  <= searching key
01 USER_NAME                 = {"N"}
02 USER_TEL                  = {"001-1234-1234"}
: 
05 USER_LOCATION             = {"earth"}
[END]
=============================================
DEBUG|2018-03-27,14:41:43.089|print log
DEBUG|2018-03-27,14:41:43.089|print log
DEBUG|2018-03-27,14:41:43.089|output:
=============================================
[START]
00 USER_ID                   = {"BBB"}  <= searching key
01 USER_NAME                 = {"N"}
:
03 USER_LOCATION             = {"saturn"}
[END]
=============================================
DEBUG|2018-03-27,14:41:43.089|print log
DEBUG|2018-03-27,14:41:43.089|print log
DEBUG|2018-03-27,14:41:43.089|output:
=============================================
[START]
00 USER_ID                   = {"AAA"}  <= searching key
01 USER_NAME                 = {"N"}
02 USER_ADDR                 = {"bla~ bla~~"}
:
010 JOB                       = {"designer"}
[END]
=============================================
:
:
```

wanted result is :

```
DEBUG|2018-03-27,14:41:43.089|output:
=============================================
[START]
00 USER_ID                   = {"AAA"}  <= searching key
01 USER_NAME                 = {"N"}
02 USER_TEL                  = {"001-1234-1234"}
: 
05 USER_LOCATION             = {"earth"}
[END]
=============================================
DEBUG|2018-03-27,14:41:43.089|output:
=============================================
[START]
00 USER_ID                   = {"AAA"}  <= searching key
01 USER_NAME                 = {"N"}
02 USER_ADDR                 = {"bla~ bla~~"}
:
010 JOB                       = {"designer"}
[END]
=============================================
```

Comment: Did you try grep with -C ?    grep -C3 "USER_ID.*AAA" AppLog.txt

Comment: @Kamaraj, thanks.. it's not fixed lines from [START] to [END].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pcregrep` works:

```
pcregrep -M \
   'DEBUG.*output:\n===*\n.*?\n.*?USER_ID.*?"AAA".*?(\n*?.*?\n*)*?===*' AppLog.txt
```

Comment: pcregrep: line 13985 of file ./AppLog.txt is too long for the internal buffer
pcregrep: check the --buffer-size option

Comment: AppLog.txt has 10GB volume.. so I am trying to use sed. (streaming text editor.)

Comment: Drat, since it's bigger than the buffer, I need to make that regex less greedy...

Comment: your advice works well until AppLog.txt is about 500MB.

Comment: @user74176, Tweaked it, please check if it works any better...

Comment: your advice is wonderfully correct but it seems AppLog.txt has very long strings at partial lines.

Comment: ok. I added --buffer-size option.. it seems works well.

Answer (score 1):

AWK--

```
awk -v RS='[\\=]+[\\=]' -v FS='\n' '/{"AAA"}/{ printf "%s%s%s%s",prevline,RT, $0, RT }{prevline="\n"$(NF-1)"\n"$NF}' ./AppLog.txt
```

1. Records Separated by ======
2. Last two lines stored in prevline
3. Printed previous stored value, separator, current value and separator again.

Answer (score 1):

A probably faster tool is awk. Using the `[END]` line as **R**ecord **S**eparator:

```
awk -vRS='\\[END\\]' -vORS='[END]\n' '/\"AAA\"/' infile | 
awk '/output:$/,/\[END\]/'
```

The first line selects the **R**ecords that contain `"AAA"`.
The second line limits the output to lines between `output:` and `[END]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grep -A 3 -B 3 'AAA' ./AppLog.txt | sed '/--/d'
```

Output:

```
DEBUG|2018-03-27,14:41:43.089|output:
=============================================
[START]
00 USER_ID                   = {"AAA"}  <= searching key
01 USER_NAME                 = {"N"}
[END]
=============================================
DEBUG|2018-03-27,14:41:43.089|output:
=============================================
[START]
00 USER_ID                   = {"AAA"}  <= searching key
01 USER_NAME                 = {"N"}
[END]
=============================================
```

`-A 3` - print other 3 lines after the matching pattern

`-B 3` - print other 3 lines before the matching pattern

Comment: did you check the option -C

Comment: @Kamaraj, thanks bro. Your answer is better. Put that in the answer so that OP can mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @WashichawbachaW, thanks.. but it's not fixed number of lines from [start] to [end]..

Answer (score 0):

For the snippet:

```
FILE=${1-data1}

# Utility functions: print-as-echo, print-line-with-visual-space.
pe() { for _i;do printf "%s" "$_i";done; printf "\n"; }
pl() { pe;pe "-----" ;pe "$*"; }

pl " Results:"
cgrep -d "/////" -w "DEBUG" +w "END" "AAA" $FILE
```

this is produced:

```
 Results:
/////
DEBUG|2018-03-27,14:41:43.089|output:
=============================================
[START]
00 USER_ID                   = {"AAA"}  <= searching key
01 USER_NAME                 = {"N"}
02 USER_TEL                  = {"001-1234-1234"}
: 
05 USER_LOCATION             = {"earth"}
[END]
/////
DEBUG|2018-03-27,14:41:43.089|output:
=============================================
[START]
00 USER_ID                   = {"AAA"}  <= searching key
01 USER_NAME                 = {"N"}
02 USER_ADDR                 = {"bla~ bla~~"}
:
010 JOB                       = {"designer"}
[END]
```

The code **cgrep** allows a window to be specified around the text (*AAA*) being searched for. So in this case we go backward to *DEBUG*, and forward to *END*.

We have used the ATT code **cgrep** for years. It needs to be compiled, but we have never encountered any errors with that process.

Here are some details on **cgrep**:

```
cgrep   shows context of matching patterns found in files (man)
Path    : ~/executable/cgrep
Version : 8.15
Type    : ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYS ...)
Home    : http://sourceforge.net/projects/cgrep/ (doc)
```

Best wishes ... cheers, drl